# Can't read one-line block of code because of horizontal bar

Tags: support, design

I've had this problem too many times now:

[image: horizontal scrollbar over code]

I can't read the code because the scrollbar is in front of it so I have to copy and paste elsewhere (which is also a bit annoying given the selectable area is very short)

Is there any way this could be improved?